# HTML element to display tooltip on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have several HTML elements that I need to display a tooltip on hover. These are not conventional HTML elements and come from a generated script on the backend, which I do not have permissions to alter. What I want to know, from a front end perspective, is how I can display a tooltip without declaring this in the HTML.

I tried using Bootstrap tooltips, but you need to declare this in the HTML tag as a title, so it's not useful. So, as the example shows below, I need some text saying 'Action' to appear in a tooltip when you hover over the 'Action' element that contains 'should'. Same will be applied when you hover over the text 'approximate number of' contained in the 'Quantifier' element - the word 'Quantifier' should be displayed. Hope this makes sense.

```
 <body>
 One string that <Action>should</Action> work is 
 <Quantifier>approximate number of</Quantifier> other things.

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("Action").hover(function(){

   });
   $("Quantifier").hover(function(){

    });
  });
 </script>
 <body>
```

So far non-conclusive, as I can only change CSS values and not tooltip text.

Comment: Are you allowed to alter HTML structure after it's rendered on the page? Like adding new classes or attributes to elements?

Comment: No, I won't have that ability once rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try updating the `title` property on those elements. One thing to note is that HTML tags will appear in lowercase when compiled.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  $('head')[0].appendChild(style);
  style.innerHTML = 
    `action, quantifier {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    action[title]:hover:after, quantifier[title]:hover:after {
      content: attr(title);  
      position: absolute;
      top: -100%;
      left: 0;
    }

    action[title]:hover:after {
      color: red;
      border: solid 1px black;
    }

    quantifier[title]:hover:after {
      color: blue;
      border: solid 1px black;
    }`;

  $('action')[0].title = 'Action';
  $('quantifier')[0].title = 'Quantifier';

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
One string that <Action>should</Action> work is 
<Quantifier>approximate number of</Quantifier> other things.
</body>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but how do I alter the CSS in the script?

Comment: Added some styling to show how to add CSS within the script.

Answer (score 1):

add a tooltip for an tag with JS/jQuery without change the html structure. You can modify the css based on requirement.

```js
  

 jQuery(function($){
//If you are able to add class then use $('.add_tooltip').hover
// use $('Quantifier, Action').hover
$('Quantifier, Action').hover(

 function () {
    //let text = $(this).html(); //this is for html content of hover element
 let text = $(this).prop("tagName");
  //Add the tag name of hover element to tooltip div
  $(this).append('<div class = "tooltip">'+text+'</div>');
  //display the tooltip with animation.
  $(this).find('.tooltip').hide().fadeIn('slow');  
 }, 

 //On hover out remove the tooltip. 
 function () {
  $(this).find('.tooltip').remove();
 }
);
});
```

```css
 Quantifier, Action{
     cursor: pointer;
     position:relative;
    }

    .tooltip{
          display: inherit;
        background: black;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
        width: 200px;
        height: 40px;
        color: #fff;
        top: 18px;
        left:10px;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

   One string that <Action>should</Action> work is 
 <Quantifier>approximate number of</Quantifier> other things.
```